# Empty frame_id in `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped`

Tags: ros, pose, rviz, ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a problem where rosbag files are the benchmarking datasets provided by an external research group. I would like to visualize the 6-DoF pose of the robot which is in the bag.
Unfortunately, the topic over which the `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped`  is published has empty `frame_id` field in the `header`. And `rviz` complains that's not a valid name.

How can I visualize the pose? What is the work around for this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374070/empty-frame_id-in-%60geometry_msgs/posestamped%60/) by [jacka122](https://answers.ros.org/users/70389/jacka122/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How can I visualize the pose?

I don't believe you can. `header.frame_id` is used to determine in which frame the poses are expressed.

Without that information, RViz would not be able to determine relative to what those poses are supposed to be placed in the 3D space it manages (ie: the render volume).

> What is the work around for this issue?

Off the top of my head, two options:

1. use the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) to fix the `.bag`s. Iterate over all messages and correct `header.frame_id`, then write them back
2. use [topic_tools/transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform) to fix the header *at runtime*: `<remap>` the original topic coming out of `rosbag` (while `play`ing) to something (say `/bad_poses`), now make `transform` subscribe to that and then have it do something like this:

   ```
   rosrun topic_tools transform \
     /bad_poses \
     /original_topic_in_the_bag \
     geometry_msgs/PoseStamped \
     'geometry_msgs.msg.PoseStamped( \
       header=std_msgs.msg.Header(
         seq=m.header.seq,stamp=m.header.stamp, \
         frame_id="my_new_frame") \
       ,pose=m.pose)' \
     --import geometry_msgs std_msgs
   ```

   note: I've chopped this up for readability, check whether the syntax is still valid, it's all a single line.

   This will publish the fixed poses on `/original_topic_in_the_bag` (you'd use the correct topic name here of course). You could have it publish on anything, I don't know whether there are other components in your node graph which expect those poses to be published on the topic in the bag.

Suggestion 2 is actually the last example on the `topic_tools/transform` wiki page.

Suggestion 1 would of course be a permanent fix.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1